# utf8 скрипт на win1251 сайте

Tags: javascript, кодировка

Необходимо сделать скрипт-виджет для вставки в любой сайт с любой кодировкой, чтобы русские символы отображались корректно (пока пробую вставить в win1251 сайт).
Пока что наткнулся на атрибут charset у тега script, но безрезультатно (т.е. результат есть - крокозябры сменились на знаки вопроса).

К сожалению, не знаю как продемонстрировать ситуацию. Если есть сервисы, позволяющие это - напишите, выложу.

Comment: Может через iframe стоит вставлять?

Comment: iframe не получится. скрипт генерит окошко, появляющееся посередине экрана.

Comment: Видимо я где то ошибся, после установки атрибута charset все стало отображаться хорошо.